# Only loading blackboard bold of a font

Tags: fonts, math-fonts, eulervm

I'm looking to use the `vvarbb` style blackboard bold font from `newpxmath` but use `eulervm` for all other math. Unfortunately it seems that `eulerpx` doesn't support the `vvarbb` option. Is there a way to load `newpxmath` only for the blackboard bold font?

Here's a MWE with the issues with each setting:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% setting 1
\usepackage[vvarbb]{newpxmath}
\usepackage{eulervm}

% setting 2
%\usepackage{eulervm}
%\usepackage[vvarbb]{newpxmath}

% setting 3
%\usepackage{newpxtext}
%\usepackage{eulerpx}

\begin{document}
$\sum a, a\in \mathbb{R}$ 
\begin{itemize}
    \item The \verb|\sum| doesn't display correctly with setting 1
    \item The $a$ isn't in \verb|euler| with setting 2
    \item The \verb|\mathbb{R}| isn't in the correct sans-serif font with setting 3, and there's no way to specify \verb|vvarbb| in \verb|eulerpx|
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `newpxmath` we find

```
\DeclareOption{vvarbb}{\px@vvarbbtrue}
```

Looking for `\px@vvarbbtrue` we see

```
% Changed macros which are not limited to a single character, and can include digits, \imath, \jmath
\def\px@@vvbb#1#2\@nil{%
        \ifiscseq{#1}{\ifcsdef{px@Bbb\@xp\@gobble\string#1}{\csname px@Bbb\@xp\@gobble\string#1\endcsname}{#1}}{%not a cs
        \csname px@Bbb#1\endcsname}
        \ifblank{#2}{\relax}{\px@@vvbb #2\@nil}}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\vvmathbb}[1]{\px@@vvbb#1\@nil}
\ifpx@vvarbb
  \let\mathbb\vvmathbb
\else
  \ifpx@varbb
    \let\mathbb\vmathbb
  \else
    \ifpx@ams\else\let\mathbb\vmathbb\fi
  \fi
\fi
```

What's this? The letters for `\vvmathbb` aren't in their standard ASCII position, so the code changes `\vvmathbb{A}` into `\px@BbbA` and similarly for other codes: an example is

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\px@BbbA}{\mathord}{lettersA}{193}
```

Digits, uppercase and lowercase letters are defined together with `\imath` and `\jmath`. There are also `\Gamma`, `\gamma`, `\Pi` and `\pi`.

OK, for the moment we need to see what `lettersA` is.

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{lettersA}{U}{npxmia}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{lettersA}{bold}{U}{npxmia}{b}{it}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{npxmia}{m}{it}
```

In the following code I use a more robust processor for the contents of `\mathbb`. Digits and the four Greek letters are not included, but can if needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tgpagella}% for Palatino
\usepackage{eulervm}

\makeatletter
% code for vvarbb
\AtBeginDocument{\newcommand{\mathbb}{\vvarbb}}

% the processing macro
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\vvarbb}{m}
 {
  \tl_map_function:nN { #1 } \__egreg_vvarbb:n
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__egreg_vvarbb:n
 {
  \token_if_cs:NTF #1
   {% the next token is a control sequence
    \str_case_e:nnF { \cs_to_str:N #1 }
     {
      {imath}{\vvarbb@Bbbimath}
      {jmath}{\vvarbb@Bbbjmath}
      % maybe add Gamma,gamma,Pi,pi
     }
    {#1}% not defined, just output it
   }
   {% not a control sequence
    \cs_if_exist_use:cF { vvarbb@Bbb#1 } { #1 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% define the math font
\DeclareSymbolFont{vvarbb}{U}{npxmia}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{vvarbb}{bold}{U}{npxmia}{b}{it}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{npxmia}{m}{it}

% define the symbols
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbA}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{193}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbB}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{194}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbC}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{195}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbD}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{196}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbE}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{197}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbF}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{198}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbG}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{199}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbH}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{200}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbI}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{201}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbJ}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{202}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbK}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{203}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbL}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{204}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbM}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{205}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbN}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{206}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbO}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{207}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbP}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{208}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbQ}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{209}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbR}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{210}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbS}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{211}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbT}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{212}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbU}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{213}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbV}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{214}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbW}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{215}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbX}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{216}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbY}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{217}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@BbbZ}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{218}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbba}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{225}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbb}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{226}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbc}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{227}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbd}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{228}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbe}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{229}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbf}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{230}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbg}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{231}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbh}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{232}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbi}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{233}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbj}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{234}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbk}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{235}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbl}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{236}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbm}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{237}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbn}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{238}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbo}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{239}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbp}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{240}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbq}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{241}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbr}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{242}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbs}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{243}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbt}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{244}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbu}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{245}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbv}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{246}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbw}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{247}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbx}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{248}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbby}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{249}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbz}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{250}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbimath}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{125}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vvarbb@Bbbjmath}{\mathord}{vvarbb}{126}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\sum a, a\in \mathbb{R}
\]
\[
\mathbb{ABCdefi\imath\jmath}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run with `xelatex` or `lualatex`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{neo-euler} 
\begin{document}

\[ \sum a, a\in \symbb{R} \]
\[ \symbb{ABCdefi} \]
\[ \sum a, a\in \BbbR \]

\end{document}
```

[image]